# Unit <SomeUnit> Recursively Uses Itself (but it doesn't)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a datamodule that's used thoughout one of our line of business apps. It's in the implementation uses clause of almost every unit in the project.

I can modify business logic and other code in the implementation section of the datamodule and compile without any issues. However, any change to the interface section of the datamodule and then compiling results in the compiler error "Unit MyDataModule recursively uses itself". A build instead of a compile makes the error go away.

This is a new one I haven't seen before. Of course, I've checked to make sure that there's no way the datamodule is recursively used, and if it were in fact, the build wouldn't change anything.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to track this down or fix it? It's really annoying to have to compile, dismiss the error dialog, and then build every time a new query or method is introduced to the datamodule.

**EDIT**: Addressing some of the comments below and in @Marjan's answer:

I'm not using Variants or debug dcus. I've tried a solution in one of the Google search results that looked [promising](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=107527) about corrupt .identcache or .local files, but that didn't pan out.

Tried @Jørn's suggestion; cleaned up all temp and compiled .dcus, did a compile, and all is well. Made a change to the interface (delared a Boolean variable in the private section of the datamodule's class declaration), and hit Ctrl+F9 to compile. Error. Did a Build, all is well. Compile then works fine. Delete the Boolean, try a compile: error.

I've got roughly 20 projects of similar size (~750K-1M LOC), none of which exhibit this behavior. I've quadruple-checked that the datamodule isn't in the interface section of any of the units in the project. The datamodule itself is not extremely large (a total of 8,345 lines from 'unit' to 'end.', including comments and blank lines). The .dfm, seen as text, is a total of 8,916 lines.

**EDIT 2**: I guess I'll have to accept (for now, anyway) that this is a compiler glitch. I'm going to try some rearranging of things to break out some of the functionality into a separate datamodule to see if it's a size limitation (items in the DFM, maybe) or something. Thanks for all the effort.

Comment: Why not just build every time? I never use compile.

Comment: Or make a new unit, add your datamodule to the interface uses clause of that unit, and refer to that unit in almost every other unit instead of the datamodule directly. (just of the top of my head, so if I'm delusional please forgive)

Comment: @Johan, your second option doesn't make sense, and your first option proves you're not working on large projects. Delphi might be fast, but for my big projects build time is 15 to 30 seconds. 30 seconds is too much: it's enough time for my eyes to drift over to Stack Overflow and start answering questions. So 30 seconds become 30 minutes. Ooops!

Comment: @Cosmin, @Johan: plus hit F9 to start the app and the IDE compiles, it does not do a build... You would have to remember to build every time before you hit F9...

Comment: Does it help to clean up temporary compiled files in the search, library and browser folders?  My first thought is that the compiler tries to use some compiled files that shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Cosmin it was just a quick blip of the top of my head. I do work on large project 100k+ lines, but I'm never temped to use compile because it's given me soo much grief. +1 LOL for the reply though.

Comment: Are you using any hairy syntax? Delphi 2007 compiler output (DCU and DCP generation) was particularly prone to this kind of breakage  when you used Generics.

Comment: @Warren: There are no generics in D2007. Generics support wasn't added until later (D2009?). This is pretty plain-vanilla Delphi code (queries, parameters, etc.); I don't even think the DM uses `for..in` anywhere.

Comment: Ah yes. Generics were in D2007.net, but didn't hit the regular Delphi win32 until 2009.

Comment: @Ken This problem has stopped occurring for me with my project after our migration to XE2. I suffered from it in D6 and D2010. But XE2 cures it.

Comment: @David, thanks. Unfortunately, the possibility of this project being transitioned to XE2 are slim and none. :( My boss sees no need for Unicode (internal business app), and has no idea what generics are, much less see any need for them. (I showed him some of the FM demos, and his response was "Nice toy. Might be good if we were writing games, but we're not." (We just got rid of our last Win2K machine a few months ago, and still run primarily XP on workstations; we do have two Windows servers, though (2003 and 2008). ;)

Comment: It could be a library path problem: with two or more units with the same name in the path, or the in `.drp file` as it could declare two different units referenced by `in` pointing to the same file.

Comment: @Vikas: This is improper behavior for StackOverflow. We are not your personal consultants, and posting comments and answers to other people's questions trying to get help for your problem is not acceptable. Your account can be suspended or even banned for unacceptable conduct. You should stop this now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are running into a compiler glitch. See LKesslers question: [Why does adding Action cause Fatal Error in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379695/why-does-adding-action-cause-fatal-error-in-delphi) for (an)other situation(s) in which this occurs.

And another: http://objectmix.com/delphi/633618-option-use-debug-dcus-causes-compiler-error.html which is related to using debug dcu's.

And if you google for it ( http://www.google.com/search?q=delphi+%22recursively+uses+itself%22+compiler+error ), it seems to have been around since D4...

I guess it being a compiler glitch is no consolation, but at least you are not alone...

**update**

I have dug up two other links with possible information on this. However they are both on experts-exchange. I normally do ***not*** include links to experts-exchange because I do not agree with their modus operandi (asking money for access to experts). In this particular case I considered "cheating" (subscribe, get the answer, post it here and cancel my subscription) to help Ken, David and anybody else afflicted with this problem. However, it doesn't feel right plus I am not about to part with my credit card details at subscription even if I can cancel before they will start charging me.

As others may hold different views on experts-exchange and/or may be keen enough to do what I am not prepared to do, the links are: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_10206864.html and http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_23848477.html
Both questions have been marked "solved" and "asker verified". Whatever that may mean.

Comment: I've been afflicted with it for years now.

Comment: I guess I have been lucky then :-) and Ken is now the owner of a reproducible test case. Now if only he could whittle it down to something reproducible for a QC report...

Comment: my 750kloc project isn't going to be much use for qc

Comment: No, not quite small enough :-)

Comment: Your link to the variants is not pertinent. Read down and you'll see the problem was with an erroneous search path configuration.

Comment: @Marjan: My situation seems to be different than lkessler's in your first link. Mine will not compile first; it requires a build. Then subsequent compiles work fine, until something changes in the interface of the datamodule. No chance of it being whittled down; other projects of similar size don't exhibit the same behavior. Checking the other links now. @David: Mine's about that size, maybe slightly larger. I have others that large that use different DMs, and they're fine.

Comment: @Ken FWIW your symptoms are identical to mine. I've got no data modules. In fact no database of any description.

Comment: @David: That's not promising. :) At least this is not a show-stopper; most of the ongoing development doesn't affect the interface of the datamodule. It's just annoying for the most part.

Comment: @Ken: It has been a while since I have personally seen this happening. So not sure what to suggest. One thing we now do daily is clean out all *.tmp files in the entire source tree because of the D2009 bug which kept creating tmp files when compiling readonly rc files. Also, we always check out both dfm and pas files. Same with dpr/dproj/mes files. This is to avoid problems when the IDE changes one behind your back while you are editing the other. That I haven't seen it again may also be due to us having migrated to D2010. I wish I could be more helpful, but I am running out of ideas fast...

Comment: @Marjan: No .tmp files anywhere in source tree. No readonly .rc files, either, and I check out .dfm and .pas files, as well as the .dpr and .dproj files. Thanks for trying so hard to help, though. (You may still get the accept for this one, if no one comes up with a solution.)

Comment: @Ken: not doing it for the accept, though I won't mind :) These things annoy the heck out of me when they crop up and if I can help make them go away, I'm happy to do so.

Comment: @Marjan: Don't part with your credit card info; it's not that important. It's not a show-stopping issue; just an annoyance. Thanks for the thought, though. :)

Comment: @Ken: thanks, don't worry, I wasn't going to. Just thought I'd include the info for anybody mad enough to actually want to...

Comment: @Sertac: I thought that worked, but I'd forgotten you had to go through a search engine to get there. Nice! For everyone's info: The solution to both involved a package named the same as the unit (eg., `uMyStuff.bpk` and `uMyStuff.pas`; I don't have that issue either. The DM in question is the only thing named anywhere close to that name, and it's only the .dfm and .pas (and resulting .dcu after a compile/build).

Comment: @Sertac: I thought I did, because I dug 'm up with google. I knew there was something with scrolling to get at the answer. I guess I picked the wrong method (copying the link instead if clicking it). Thanks for putting me on the right track again...

Answer (score 4):

Hit the same issue, however, my solution was very small and was able to locate the root: the unit that I was trying to add to my existing project had the same name as my project. Renamed project and that was the end of that.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the issue here. There's only one unit I have this issue with (a `TDataModule`), and it's name is nothing like anything else in the project. (It's the only `pas/dfm` pair in the whole project whose names start with 'dm`.)

Comment: Nice one, I couldn't figure it out. It was a weird error, thanks!

Comment: I think this is the best and most common answer. Just rename the pascal file so it doesn't match the project file name. Fixed mine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Been thinking about it.
Delphi can put the DCU in a different folder than the pas file.
If the search order during compile is flaky it will find the DCU first and use the interface section from that, then find the PAS file and use the implementation there.

If you force the DCU to be in the same dir as the PAS file, does the problem go away?

Comment: The .DCU for the datamodule is in the same folder as the source. (I have SVN configured to ignore .dcu files during checkin.) I also mentioned that I've deleted all the .dcus for the entire project and tried a new compile. Thanks for trying to answer, though. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

It is a compiler glitch, as someone else said, but I have found it helpful to try working with your library path and your search path, and your DCU output paths inside each project you have in your group. simplify the search and library paths, and with output DCU paths, make sure for example, that each project puts its DCU files in a separate folder that is NOT in the search or library path of the other projects.

Overlapping, or complex search or library paths, and ESPECIALLY shared DCUs tends to bring on such problems.

Comment: Thanks. This dm is used by the main app I'm having the problem with and one other (basically a read-only version of the main one with limited functionality). They share the same folder for the DM. The .DCU is the same location as the .pas/.dfm, and there is no other instance of the .pas/.dfm/.dcu on the entire drive. Other than that, there's nothing using anything in the project folder. I'm pretty sure there's no overlapping search or lib paths, and these two related projects are the only ones using the DM. I'll check the path issue in the AM to make sure.

Comment: No overlapping paths anywhere. :( Also did another scan for the .DCU on the entire drive, just to double-check. Only one of them found, and it's in the right location.) Thanks again, though, for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Delphi with the "-nocache" command line parameter? It solved a lot of problems to me. I found this solution somewhere on the Embarcadero forums.

Comment: Mine either. Thanks for the effort, @Bozzy.

Answer (score 0):

We had same issues. It happens randomly after modify some unrelated files.

In our case trouble was:

1. Some file (x.pas) have "commonUnit.pas" in uses part - but it doesn't need it
2. modify "commonUnit.pas" or better "SomeConsts.pas" (whitch is used by commonUnit.pas but not by x.pas)
3. compile (sometimes) failed with message "Unit commonUnit.pas Recursively Uses Itself"
4. rebuild project fixes issue

Our project environment is:

- one "Compiled" folder (included in SEARCH path at first place)
- **all** DCU are compiled to this folder

Comment: As I said, it's a datamodule. It's used in the `implementation` uses clause of almost every other unit in the project (where it is actually needed). The error only happens when I do something that changes the `interface` section of the datamodule itself, not when I change other units; it does *not* happen when I modify unrelated files. The `dcu` files are in the same folder as the `pas` files, and deleting every single dcu and doing a build does not stop the error from happening again; neither does checking out the entire project to a new folder.